# Disallow assignment of values

Tags: haskell, purescript, unification, impredicativetypes, rank-n-types

I'm experimenting with a type-level permission system, and I'm trying to disallow assignment of values which do not originate from the same "source", i.e:

```
data A = A { a :: Value, b :: Value }

modify :: A -> A
modify (A v) = A $ v { a = v.a } -- should work
modify (A v) = A $ v { a = v.b } -- should *NOT* work
```

I've experimented with rank N (or impredicative?) types:

```
type Value = forall a. Value a ...
```

but both cases above unify. If I constrain `a`:

```
type Value = forall a. Unique a => Value a ...
```

both cases don't. Is there a way to achieve something like that? Is it possible in Haskell?

(Note: the `Value` constructor would not be public, i.e. there's no way to create a standalone `Value`.)

Comment: Wouldn't that break *referential transparency*?

Comment: Add a phantom type parameter to `Value` and instantiate it with two different types inside `A`; e.g. using `TypeLits`: `data A = A (Value 1) (Value 2)`. This is essentially nothing more than having two (or `k` for `k : Nat`) distinct, isomorphic `Value` types. (Aside: the first thing you say you tried is called 'existensial' types, not 'impredicative' or 'rank-N', which are both entirely different things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user2407038 mentionned, you could use phantom types to do what you want.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

data ValueType = A | B

data Value :: ValueType -> * where
    Value :: Int → Value t

data V = V { a :: Value A, b :: Value B }

modify ∷ V -> V
modify v = v { a = a v }  -- no error
modify v = v { a = b v }  -- Couldn't match type ‘'B’ with ‘'A’
```

However, there is a workaround:

```
modify ∷ V -> V
modify v = v { a = Value $ getBValue (b v) }
    where getBValue (Value x) = x
```

But you can prevent the user from writing `getBValue` if you hide the `Value` constructor (by not exporting it). But that would mean that there is absolutely no way to extract the actual value out of a `Value`. You could still instantiate `Value` for the `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` so that you can work with those wrapped values directly. But you would have to change `Value` to a more general form. Here is an example:

```
data Value :: ValueType -> * -> * where
    Value :: a -> Value t a

instance Functor (Value t) where
    fmap f (Value x) = Value (f x)

instance Applicative (Value t) where
    pure = Value
    Value f <*> Value x = Value (f x)

instance Monad (Value t) where
    Value x >>= f = f x
```

Comment: You might want to either not use the non-ASCII unicode symbols or add `UnicodeSyntax` to the language extensions (personally, I'd suggest the former since it is probably a bit more clear in the context of an answer to a programming question).

Comment: Sorry, UnicodeSyntax is by default in my GHCi, I edited my code to use ASCII characters, thanks.